# What would be causing my program to crash using a cout statement and connect()

Tags: c++, qt

I don't understand why my `cout` statement, which should output the price of a stock after the json file is read in, keeps crashing. Below is the code with the `cout`:

```cpp
Json::Value chartData = IEX::stocks::delayedQuote(symbolSearchedStd);
cout << chartData[0]["delayedPrice"].asDouble() << endl;
```

I can do `cout << chartData` and see that the JSON is outputting the proper format with `"delayedPrice"`:

```
{
    "delayedPrice" : 33.058999999999997,
    "delayedPriceTime" : 1621930415167,
    "delayedSize" : 101,
    "high" : 33.719999999999999,
    "low" : 32.649999999999999,
    "processedTime" : 1657842169267,
    "symbol" : "TWTR",
    "totalVolume" : 17031983
}
```

And I also have it connected to a `QTimer` to update every couple of seconds:

```cpp
connect(&dataTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(readData()));
    dataTimer.start(5000);
```

But still, for some reason, the `cout` statement will not output the delayed price as a `double`. Why? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: My advice is to simplify things and get the cout to work without a signal and slot.

Comment: My JSON is a bit rusty, but is `chartData[0]` correct? Maybe try without `[0]`.

Comment: Read [*how to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @drescherjm I have already done this actually, it couts strings and ints just fine, just not the chartData

Comment: ChartData is an object, not a list, so [0] looks wrong